# jqxListBox:Check listbox item based on value member

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxwidgets

Hi I have the following code

```
var source =
        {
                 datatype: "json",
                    datafields: [
                        { name: 'Name' },
                        { name: 'ID'},     
                    ],
                    localdata: data
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        $("#polistbox").jqxListBox({ source: dataAdapter, displayMember: "Name", valueMember: "ID", checkboxes: true, width: '255px', height: '100px'});
```

I want to check one item using the value member.
ie) I want to check the item having value 2.How can i achieve this?
I found the following solution http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/vv3gK/ .
But how can i achieve this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean check by index or value? Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/l0oky/vv3gK/37/).

You could always use checkIndex like so:

```
$("#polistbox").jqxListBox('checkIndex',2);
```

In the link that you gave me - It showed you everything you need, unless you haven't told us something else.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but maybe someone will use it.
This works for me.

```
var ID = id you want;    
var jqItem = $("#polistbox").jqxListBox('getItemByValue', ID);
$("#polistbox").jqxListBox('selectItem', jqItem );
```